# ROS Answers SE migration: Kinect amcl

Tags: navigation, kinect, youbot, amcl, 2d-pose-estimate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody!
I am testing amcl on a KUKA youBot equipped with a Kinect.
Following this tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide
I move the robot with a joypad on the known map to check the amcl.

This is what I obtain:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn0Bde0BjSs

As you can see the correction for translation is quite good, te problem is that odom doesn't turn enough to in order to correct odometry in rotation.

Here is my amcl file

```
<launch>
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="base_frame_id" value="/base_footprint"/>
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="omni"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.2" />
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="10.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="60"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="1000"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="10000"/>
  <!--param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/-->
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.5"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.95"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.15"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.03"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.01"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.002"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="4.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="/odom"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.001"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0.35"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_y" value="1.08"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_a" value="1.57"/>
  <param name="first_map_only" value="true"/>
  <param name="laser_max_range" value="4.0"/>
  <param name="laser_min_range" value="0.6"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

The youBot odometry is not so good, so I gave a high weight to odom parameters and I tried to trust much more the laser with a very low "laser_sigma_hit" parameter.

Any suggesion to make it works better?
Thank you guys

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11795/kinect-amcl/) by [Lorenzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/293/lorenzo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for supplying the bag file; that always helps in trying to debug this sort of issue.

It looks like the robot is consistently underreporting the actual rotation.  I watched the scans accumulate in the odom frame in rviz (as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/448/is-there-a-good-way-to-verify-my-odometry-data-is#808)), and would estimate that it's underreporting by 5-10 degrees per rotation.

`amcl`'s odometry model assumes zero-mean noise. It has a hard time correcting for systematic bias, which your robot seems to exhibit.  If your robot is indeed always underreporting rotation (more data might be required to verify that), then I would try to correct the odometry before sending it to `amcl`.  You might try a variation on the [TurtleBot calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_calibration/Tutorials/Calibrate%20Odometry%20and%20Gyro), which uses a wall as a fixed feature to compare to.  Or you might just inflate the reported yaw differences by 1-3%.  Either way, if there's a consistent bias, it should be possible to do a one-time correction (not a periodic re-calibration). Such a fix could probably be incorporated into the YouBot odometry calculation somewhere.

If fixing the odometry is not feasible, I would try tuning `amcl`'s [odometry parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl#Parameters).  In this situation, `odom_alpha1` is probably the most important one to increase, with `odom_alpha4` coming next.  I would leave the other parameters low (at their defaults).

I would not increase confidence on the laser model; the Kinect isn't really giving you high-quality laser scans.  Instead, I would take the laser model configuration from [turtlebot_navigation](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/file/38b767c83d5c/turtlebot_navigation/config/amcl_turtlebot.launch).

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5